# Redirecting Discord DM in a specific channel

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I started programming a discord bot using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org), and I cant figure out a way for the bot to redirect received messages in a specific channel on my server as an embed.

Here's my code so far:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Logged in!');
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
        msg.author.send("bruh dming me has literally no point");
        return;
        const messageEmbed = {
            color: 0x00ff00,
            title: 'Received DM',
            author: {
                name: 'Me'
            },
            description: 'I received the following DM:',
            thumbnail: {
            },
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'Author:',
                    value: message.author,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Message:',
                    value: messageEmbed,
                    inline: false,
                },
            ],
        }
        client.channels.cache.get('726515463017988176').send(messageEmbed)
    }
});

client.login('this is where my token was but i had to replace it lol');

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
    if (message.channel.type === 'text') {
        if (message.content === '!ip') {
            message.channel.send('[insert server ip here]');
        }
    }
});
```

PS: as you can probably tell, I'm new to JS.

Edit: I managed to semi get it to work now, it sends every message received in the chat but every answer (`msg.author.send("bruh dming me has literally no point");`) as well. Is there a way to skip Messages with specific content and is there a way to put the redirected message in an embed with date, author and message?

My code now:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Logged in!');
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
        msg.author.send("bruh dming me has literally no point");
//      return;
        const messageEmbed = {
            color: 0x00ff00,
            title: 'Recieved DM',
            author: {
                name: 'Me'
            },
            description: 'I recieved the following DM:',
            thumbnail: {
            },
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'Author:',
                    value: msg.author,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Message:',
                    value: msg.content,
                    inline: false,
                },
            ],
        }
//      if (msg.content) == "bruh dming me has literally no point")
        client.channels.cache.get('726515463017988176').send(msg.content)
        client.channels.cache.get('726515463017988176').send(msg.author)
    }
});

client.login('tokentokentokentokentokentokentoken(secret)');

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
    if (message.channel.type === 'text') {
        if (message.content === '!ip') {
            message.channel.send('[insert server ip here]');
        }
    }
});
```

Probably the last edit:
I managed to get it to work by using another embed template. Code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('you probably already know what belongs here xd')

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Logged in!')
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.type === "dm" && message.author.id !== client.user.id) {
        console.log("-----DM-----")
        console.log(message.content)
        console.log(message.author.tag)
        console.log("-----DM-----")
        message.author.send("bruh dming me has literally no point");
        client.channels.cache.get('726919268142415973').send({
                embed: {
                color: 0x8b0000,
                    author: {
                        name: "I recieved the following DM:",
                        icon_url: message.author.avatarURL
                    },
                    title: message.author.tag,
                    description: message.content,
                    timestamp: new Date(),
                    footer: {
                        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
                        text: "Staff"
                    }
                }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please spend a minute reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Could you please tell us a bit more about what you've tried already? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `client.on('message')` callback, you've got `return`, which ends the function's execution. This means any code after it (in the same function) is not reachable. It should work if you remove it.

- [return | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#:%7E:text=When%20a%20return%20statement%20is,where%20x%20is%20a%20number.&text=If%20the%20value%20is%20omitted%2C%20undefined%20is%20returned%20instead.)
- [callback function | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Though optional, it's also advisable to make sure you end every statement with a semicolon.

Comment: Hi! First of all, thanks for the quick Response! I removed it, but now it doesnt respond to the message and it crashes with the following error: ```ReferenceError: message is not defined```

Comment: That's because you defined it as 'msg', not 'message'.  Use 'msg' instead, on the lines where you mistakenly used 'message'.

Comment: For your second field value, you've got `messageEmbed` which doesn't really make sense. Did you mean `msg.content`?

Comment: ```messageEmbed``` is the embed i want to use to Redirect the data to the channel.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to replace the following two lines :

```js
client.channels.cache.get('726515463017988176').send(msg.content);
client.channels.cache.get('726515463017988176').send(msg.author);
```

With :

```js
client.channels.cache.get('726515463017988176').send(messageEmbed);
```

Comment: i replaced it and the embed wouldnt work, is something wrong with the embed itself maybe?

Comment: @Delight maybe try to remove the empty `thumbnail` part ?

Comment: I used a different embed template, now it works. Ill put the Code in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the bot to send it's answer as well, you can add replace the very first `if` statement with the following :

```js
if (msg.channel.type === "dm" && message.author.id !== client.user.id) {
```

Hope this helps :)